# How to prevent from uploading shell

Tags: php, security, mod-security

What is the best way to prevent from uploading c99shell,r57shell and another php sheller? i want when an attacker upload a shell the sheller don't show for him. 
I use mod_security ver 1.x 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You fix your application so that 1) the attacker can't upload malicious content or 2) once it's uploaded it can't be executed in any manner.

Comment: Ok, if the attacker get the password of joomla with trojan, and upload a shell from the joomla panel, so is there any fault in joomla application?

Comment: If that happens, you have far larger problems to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Install a tool such as [maldet](http://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) to scan uploaded files, and the entire system on a regular basis. It's designed specifically to catch malicious software in shared web hosting environments.

Comment: I also like [tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/). They have an open-source version that's decent.

Comment: @NathanC Tripwire is a good thing to have, though it doesn't address this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

from [link](http://www.thonky.com/how-to/prevent-base-64-decode-hack/)

First, add the following lines to your php.ini file. Check with your hosting provider to find out if and how you can edit your php.ini file.

```
allow_url_fopen = off
allow_url_include = off
disable_functions = "apache_child_terminate, apache_setenv, define_syslog_variables, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, eval, exec, fp, fput, ftp_connect, ftp_exec, ftp_get, ftp_login, ftp_nb_fput, ftp_put, ftp_raw, ftp_rawlist, highlight_file, ini_alter, ini_get_all, ini_restore, inject_code, mysql_pconnect, openlog, passthru, php_uname, phpAds_remoteInfo, phpAds_XmlRpc, phpAds_xmlrpcDecode, phpAds_xmlrpcEncode, popen, posix_getpwuid, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, posix_setuid, posix_uname, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_nice, proc_open, proc_terminate, shell_exec, syslog, system, xmlrpc_entity_decode"
```

Comment: Hopefully shared hosting is not in use.  If it is, step 1 is to stop using shared hosting.